# Removing duplicate records in the Attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, delete, duplicates

I need to remove the duplicate objects in my attribute table (see the image attached), but I can't find a way to do so.

I saw questions asked with python that it NOT relevant to my case

[image]

Comment: Try the Delete duplicates by attribute tool.